# Including a for loop within a dplyr chain

Tags: r, dplyr

I am in the process of cleaning some data on customer behavior and I want to identify and filter out the *second* time that customers perform a certain event. As this is one element of a larger data manipulation project, ideally I would like to add this as three lines to a longer dplyr chain.

There are two pieces of logic involved here:

1. Identifying the first row of the second event: The previous row has
   an end_pct value higher than 0.9, the current row has an end_pct
   value value below 0.2, and the previous and current rows have the
   same customer_id
2. Identifying the subsequent rows: If the previous
   row has ‘yes’ for second_event and the previous and current rows
   have the same customer_id
3. Filter out the second time events

This is the dplyr code I have used for each of these operations:

```
mutate(second_time = ifelse(lag(pct_completed,1) > 0.9 & pct_completed < .2 & lag(customer_id,1) == customer_id, "yes", "no")) %>%
mutate(second_time = ifelse(lag(second_time,1)=="yes"&lag(customer_id,1) == customer_id, "yes", second_time)) %>%
filter(second_time = "no")
```

If I run the second mutate function above in a normal dplyr chain it will only mark the second row in the second event as "yes", not any subsequent ones. Hence I believe that I need to write a for loop to catch all of the remaining events in the second phase.

I've attached some [sample data here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-PaxTw3xOPZWEM3NHFwRGNNU3M) to illustrate the problem.

If anyone has any good suggestions about how to write a for loop that can be incorporated into a dplyr chain, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose an easier solution.

- We group by customer (since everything is calculated *within* customer).
- We detect a change of event, similar to your current logic and set a flag.
- We do a cumulative sum of flags to count which event we are in.
- We filter on when the cumulative sum is 2.

.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(customer_id) %>% 
  mutate(flag = row_number() > 1 &        #to avoid NA's on the first rows of each customer
           (pct_completed < 0.2) & 
           (lag(pct_completed) > 0.9),
         event_nr = cumsum(flag) + 1) %>% 
  filter(event_nr == 2)
```

Comment: Thanks @Axeman. If I want to incorporate this into a larger chain of commands and keep the data at an event level, do I add an ungroup(customer_id) after the filter command? Or is it better to run this without the filter and create a separate data frame and then merge this with the main one via left_join and *then* run the filter?

Comment: That's impossible for me to tell from the available information.

Comment: No worries, I checked and I don't need to do either, actually. Your code suggestion works perfectly - just one note, is that filter(event_nr ==  1) is correct in the circumstances outlined above, which is that I want to remove 2nd and later events.